# Check/Change Background position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a button that when clicked the background position changes (and I don't want to use CSS because I want it to stick, not just do it when clicked). Then when the user clicks a save button it checks the background position to see which setting to save (on or off). I am using jQuery and from what I have seen online it looks like I am getting everything right, but it isn't working, so something isn't right. Here is code:

```
function onoffButton(i, g)
{
    $(i).click(function () {
        if ($(g).css("backgroundPosition") == "0px -20px") {
            $(g).css("backgroundPosition", "0px 0px");
        } else {
            $(g).css("backgroundPosition", "0px -20px");
        }
    });
}
```

Which would then be called by something like this:

```
onoffButton("#testswitchRating", "#faviconswitch");
```

And then to check them to save settings:

```
if ($("#ratingswitch").css("backgroundPosition") == "0px 0px") {
    createCookie('showRatings', 0,365);
}

if ($("#ratingswitch").css("backgroundPosition") == "0px -20px") {
    createCookie('showRatings', 1,365);
}
```

I'm reading the cookie here:

```
function checkSettings()
{
if (readCookie('showRatings') == 0) {
$('.rating').css('display', 'none');
$('#ratingswitch').css('background-position','0px 0px');
} else {
$('.rating').css('display', 'inline');
$('#ratingswitch').css('background-position','0px -20px');
}
}
```

Then I call it here:

```
<body onload="checkSettings();">
```

Comment: Did you try basic debugging as in alert($(g).css("backgroundPosition")); to check what value is being retrived?

Comment: Ah... there the problem is! Have you initialised the background position in either HTML style attribute or using jQuery?

Comment: I wasn't doing either. I just tried your answer and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Where are you reading the cookie to set the position when the page loads?

Comment: I'm going to post it in my question. Not enough space here...

Comment: The % is the culprit. Not a proper solution but as a workaround I can suggest replacing 0px with 0% in the comparison. But check whether it works in all browsers.

Comment: That is part of the problem though, I'm not using the `%` sign anywhere, I am just using `0px` so I have no idea where that came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best possible suggestion here is to simply use a CSS class like `.altPosition`, and define the difference in your CSS file.  Then use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) like so:

```
$(i).click(function () {
    $(g).toggleClass("altPosition");
});
```

For saving your cookie, you can then just do something with `$(g).is(".altPosition")` to detect which state it is in, and `toggleClass()` can take a second parameter as a boolean for on or off for reading your cookies:

```
// to write:
createCookie("showRatings", $("#ratingsswitch").is(".altPosition"), 365);
// and to read:
$("#ratingsswitch").toggleClass("altPosition", readcookie("showRatings"));
```

And then in your css:

```
#faviconswitch { 
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#faviconswitch.altPosition { 
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}
```

Comment: And instead of this $(g).css("backgroundPosition") == "0px -20px") use $(g).hasClass("altPosition");